# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}x\ln\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: analysis, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}x\ln\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2+y^2}}.$$

*Attempt*. It is indefinite form is $0(-\infty)$. For curves $x=0,~y=0,~y=x$ the limit equals $0$, so the limit could be $0$, if it exists. But I find it hard to estimate $|x\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|$ and use sandwich theorem (inequalites of $\ln$, such as $\ln x\leq x-1<x,~x>0$ didn't help here).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $(x,y)$ closed enough to zero, then
\begin{align*}
|x\ln(x^{2}+y^{2})|&=-|x|\ln(x^{2}+y^{2})\\
&=|x|\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)\\
&\leq C|x|\cdot\dfrac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1/4}}\\
&\leq C\cdot\dfrac{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1/2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1/4}}\\
&= C(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1/4}\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Since$$
\lim_{u \to 0^+} u |\ln u| = 0
$$
and$$
|x \ln\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2 + y^2}}| \leqslant \sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2 + y^2}} |\ln\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2 + y^2}}|, \quad \forall (x,y) ≠ (0,0)
$$
so$$
\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)} x \ln\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2 + y^2}} = 0.
$$

Comment: You probably ment $|x\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|=-|x|\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)$ close to $(0,0).$

Comment: Wondering what the `smash[b]` is for...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Normal, `\smash[b]`, and `\smash`:$$\sqrt{y^2},\quad\sqrt{\smash[b]{y^2}},\quad\sqrt{\smash{y^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that.

Answer (score 1):

By polar coordinates $r\to 0$

$$x\ln\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2+y^2}}=r\cos \theta \ln r \to 0$$

indeed

- $0 \le |r\cos \theta \ln r| \le |r\ln r|$

and

- $r\ln r \to 0$

Comment: When I posted my answer, I also ignored the fact that $\ln r<0$ when $r→0^+$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Oh yes of course! I fix, Thanks.